# How do I save and load specific User Data locally in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, json, .net, mvvm, maui

I am trying to build a .net MAUI Application that should save the data of the user locally on the device.
On app startup I would like to check if there is already previously saved data or not and if so load the data to show and manipulate in the app.

As the Data is not very complex, some Lists containing DateTime Objects and a few strings and integers, I was trying around using JSON. The Data should be loaded into a class "UserData" that has all the neccessary Properties.

The class looks something like this:

```
    public partial class UserData : ObservableObject
    {

        public UserData()
        {
        }


        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<DateTime> takeOffs = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<DateTime> landings = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<RecencyItem> recencyData = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateTime? ldgExpiration;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateTime? takeOffExpiration;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isRecent = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string recencyText = "NOT ENOUGH DATA";

    }
}
```

I am trying to stick to MVVM and Instantiating all the Classes under MauiProgram.cs like so:

```
        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<UserData>()
            .AddSingleton<MainPage>()
            .AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
            .AddSingleton<TakeOffsPage>()
            .AddSingleton<TakeoffsViewModel>()
            .AddSingleton<LandingsPage>()
            .AddSingleton<LandingsViewModel>()
            .AddTransient<AddActivityPage>()
            .AddTransient<AddActivityViewModel>()
            .AddSingleton<CertificatesPage>()
            .AddSingleton<CertificatesViewModel>()
            .AddTransient<AddCertificatesPages>()
            .AddTransient<AddCertificatesViewModel>();
```

Thats how my Json Deserializing and Serializing looks like:

```
public static UserData GetData(string jsonFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(jsonFilePath))
        {
            using var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath);
            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserData>(data);
        }
        else return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}

public static void SaveData(string jsonFilePath, UserData userData)
{
    try
    {
        string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userData);
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(jsonFilePath);
        writer.Write(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

How and where do I best implement the JSON File deserialization while sticking to MVVM? Or is there a better way than JSON for my usecase?

So far I successfully am able to Save the Data I create to the JSON, but I am not able to load it properly.

edit: the data contained in the JSON doesn´t get loaded into the UserData Object at all, this is how I try to achieve it so far:

```
    public MainViewModel(UserData userData)
{
    this.UserData = userData;
    LoadUserData(JSON_FILE_NAME);
}

public void LoadUserData(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        string jsonFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, fileName);
        UserData loadedUserData = JsonService.GetData(jsonFilePath);
        if (loadedUserData != null)
        {
            this.UserData = loadedUserData;
            Debug.WriteLine("Userdata loaded from JSON");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Could not load JSON file {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Also I am not really sure where the best point in the Application is to load the data from the JSON.

Comment: "I am not able to load it properly." isn't a helpful description of the problem.  What **specific** problem do you have when trying to load it?  And how you save/load data really has nothing to do with MVVM

Comment: @Jason I edited my original post to hopefully clarify my problem

Comment: Have you verified that it's saved correctly?  Have you verified that the data is loaded from the file?  Have you checked the contents of the string before you deserialize it?  There are a lot of basic debugging steps that you should be doing to hunt this down.

Comment: I verified that is saves corretly. The Data is also correctyl loaded from the file. The Serialization and Deserialization seem to work correctly, as while Debugging the during Deserialization created Object contains all the Data from the json file.

Comment: If that is true then the problem must be elsewhere in your code

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint to debug it, to see exactly where the error is reported.